# How to validate "2016-05-16 06:00:00.0" in symfony3 form type?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I am trying to validate "2016-05-16 06:00:00.0" with symfony form component. This is my validation rule

```
$builder->add("start", DateTimeType::class, [
        'format' => "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S",
        'invalid_message' => 'Really bad format'
    ]);
```

For some reason though it is failing to validate. I tried .0 instead of .S in the end, and still no luck.

Comment: Is it Symfony 3 or 2.8?

Comment: @felipsmartins Symfony3

Comment: It works for me (despite I'm adding "widget" => "single_text")

Answer (score 0):

Either you can add assert for "DateTime" in your entity, where you can add

```
  @Assert\DateTime()
```

and inside it you can specify formats (default format is Y-m-d H:i:s), see for more details http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/DateTime.html

```
@Assert\DateTime(format = Y-m-d H:i:s)
```

or you can add this validation constraint in your form by using

```
->add('fieldname', 'DateTime', array(
       'constraints' => new DateTime(format = Y-m-d H:i:s) 
))
```

also add 'use' statement

```
 use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\DateTime;
```

hope this helps, all the best

Comment: I'm afraid you've misunderstood the OP question.